# L.esri.query - where is it?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, esri-leaflet

I have a website that is displaying a MapBox map, using Leaflet. One of the layers is generated from an Esri ArcGIS Rest interface, using Esri's Leaflet plugin: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/

My current task is to allow the user to click on the map, and then to display information for nearby features in the ArcGIS layer. From reading the docs, Esri's [L.esri.query](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html) object should be able to manage this.

My problem? L.esri.query is undefined.

Initially, I'd just been loading the v1.0 JS file:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/1.0.0/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
```

When that didn't work, I tried loading the v2.0 JS file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
```

And when that didn't work, I included every plugin listed at https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/download/:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.clustered-feature-layer/2.0.0-beta.1/esri-leaflet-clustered-feature-layer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.renderers/2.0.1/esri-leaflet-renderers.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.gp/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-gp.js"></script>
```

And still, nothing. So, the question, where is L.esri.query() defined?

Comment: Have you loaded the correct version of Leaflet itself?   http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.css and http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are loading in Leaflet itself? Here is a 'Hello World' map taken from the examples, with the query function logged in the console, and then proceed with a working example (showing that it is defined and working as intended):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdJyMz?editors=1111

Working code here for convenience:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Esri Leaflet Quickstart</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.js"></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map("map").setView([37.75, -122.23], 10);

  L.esri.basemapLayer("Topographic").addTo(map);

  console.log(L.esri.query);

  var latlng = L.latLng(45.51, -122.70);

  var query = L.esri.query({
      url: 'http://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/stops/FeatureServer/0'
  });

  query.nearby(latlng, 2000).where("direction='East'").orderBy('stop_id', 'ASC');

  query.count(function(error, count, response){
      console.log('Found ' + count + ' features');
  });

  query.ids(function(error, ids, response){
      console.log(ids.join(', ') + 'match the provided parameters');
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Digging through the source, I found a remark about moving the tasks from the L.esri.Tasks namespace - so L.esri.Tasks.query() was changed to L.esri.query(). So I tried L.esri.Tasks,query(), and that worked. Somehow, I have an older version of L.esri being loaded.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved.